# select2 maximumSelectionSize not working after removing element

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-3

I m using select2 plugin Version: 3.4.4
My problem with maximumSelectionSize of select2. i want to allow add custom tag to user so i used select2 with tags my code is

```
$('#color_group').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    placeholder: "Select color Name",
    tags: ['red', 'blue'],
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
});
```

its working fine its allows user to add only 1 color but when user remove that color try to add some other color its say `You can only select 1 item` i don't know whats wrong with select2. and tags are dynamically data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try update again value of maximumSelectionSize in select2 like this

```
   $('#color_group').select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "Select color Name",
        tags: ['red', 'blue'],
        maximumSelectionSize: 1
    });


   //add this code after above code and try    
    $('#color_group').on('change', function() {
            $('#color_group').select2({
                theme: "bootstrap",
                placeholder: "Select Group Name",
                tags: ['red', 'blue'],
                maximumSelectionSize: 1
            });
        });
```